# como ponerle hora de fin a este codigo

Tags: javascript, html, json

Hola alguien me ayuda a ponerle hora de fin a este codigo, y si se pudiera en horario local,
EJEMPLO: (28 de Oct. del 2020 19:00:00 GMT-5)
saludos.
aqui dejo el codigo:

```
var today = new Date();
var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

if(mm == 12) {
  mm = '05';
yyyy = yyyy + 2;
} else {
mm = parseInt(mm) + 1;
mm = String(mm).padStart(-1, '0');
}
var timerdate = 10 + '/' + 29 + '/' + 2020;
```

Comment: Puedes ser más específico con lo que quieres hacer Y qué sucederá cuando finalice

Comment: hola, gracias por la ayuda, ese codigo actualmente finaliza con un dia en especifico quiero, que finalize con el dia y la hora en especifico... y agregar algunas frases al culminar el contador ejemplo (evento culminado)

Comment: USA la función setInterval esa función hace que el bloque de código dentro de esta se ejecuta cada segundo 